# Drawing static full screen images using DirectX11

Tags: directx

My question is as follows. In most tutorials that I've seen there is a setup part of DirectX11 where you do something like this:

```
// Set the refresh rate of the back buffer.
if(m_vsync_enabled)
{
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = numerator;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = denominator;
}
else
{
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
}
```

Which either sets the refresh to be as fast as possible or synched with the monitor.

However in the application that I need I only want to refresh the screen when I tell the system to do it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers have nothing to do with the actual refreshing, which happens when you invoke `Present`. You can call it once per second and screen will be refreshed just once.

Comment: I had forgotten about this question. Yeah. I've figured as much a while back. But thank you for confirming it